# laravel sql statement - how to add additional clause to where isnot - 'where' '!=' OR

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I want to grab all users from a database, except 2.

I used to grab all except one with this code:

```
$users = User::where('name', '!=','name1')->get();
```

but I'm unsure how to add an additional name to this.

Many thanks,

Mike

Comment: You can also chain where(...)->where(...) clauses together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `WhereNotIn`

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-wherenotin)

```
$users = User::whereNotIn('name', ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'])->get();
```

Hope this help you.